# Надпись "Не оставил меток" на странице профиля (ошибка подсчета кол-ва меток)

Tags: дефект, метки, профиль-участника

На странице профиля в сводке пишет надпись "Не оставил меток" (и в разделе "метки" пишет тоже), хотя я оставлял метки. Тут ошибка в подсчетах (или дефект надписи)

[image: Скриншот дефекта]

[image: Вопрос с метками]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, это всё кэш. Стоит немного подождать и проверить снова. В крайнем случае, некоторые данные могут пересчитываться до суток.